# Live in Florida, but work 100% remotely for a Virginia company. Do I owe VA state income tax?

Tags: united-states, taxes, state-income-tax, payroll-taxes

I am moving to Florida in a couple weeks. I will be working 100% remotely for a company that is based in Virginia. Will I still have to pay state income tax to Virginia? Do I have to notify my employer to remove the state income tax after I move? Answers are appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

Yes you have to notify your employer. You will have to pay taxes on your Virginia income to Virginia from the start of the year until when your leave the state.

You will have to establish residence in Florida to prove to Virginia that you no longer live there. You should register to vote in Florida, Register your vehicles in Florida, get a Florida Driver license. Have all bills and other mail sent to Florida.