# Do I have to pay New York state tax? Freelancer with New York LLC, living in Florida

Tags: united-states, limited-liability-company, state-income-tax, new-york, florida

I'm a freelance software developer working from home. I work through a single-member LLC registered in New York. I previously lived in New York and paid New York state tax, but I have moved to Florida. One of my clients is still headquartered in New York. Do I have New York source income / have to pay New York state tax while living and working in Florida?

Comment: Not exactly the same states, but related: https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/39055/live-in-florida-but-work-100-remotely-for-a-virginia-company-do-i-owe-va-stat

Comment: thanks, appreciate the link. different though, that's an employment situation (W-2 or 1099), which is different to and LLC that is treated as a passthrough entity for tax purposes.

Comment: The LLC or you personally? Business vs individual. NYS is actively hunting those whose residency requirements are questionable. Did you have residency in NYS last year?